# detect and linkify instagram within string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a way to linkify a string that contains the following...

Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsom Instagram: @instausername Lorem ipsum

the code need to make this `"Instagram: @instausername"` into this `"<a href='https://www.instagram.com/@instausername'> Instagram: @instausername<a/>"`.  So the final string should look like this..

```
Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsom <a href='https://www.instagram.com/@instausername'> Instagram: @instausername<a/> Lorem ipsum
```

I'm not that familiar with regex but I suppose it can be solved using regex, can anyone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Are you referring to usernames that start with `@`?

Comment: Hi Pedro, sorry I should have mentioned that but yes I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An Instagram username is limited to 30 characters and must contain
>   only letters, numbers, periods, and underscores. You can’t include
>   symbols or other punctuation marks as a part of your username.

Based on this, you can use:

```
    string subjectString = "Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsom Instagram: @instausername Lorem ipsum";
    string resultString = null;
    try {
        resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "Instagram: (@[^ ]+)", "<a href='https://www.instagram.com/$1'> Instagram: $1<a/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        Console.WriteLine(resultString);
    } catch (ArgumentException ex) {
        // Syntax error in the regular expression
    }
```

---

```
Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsom <a href='https://www.instagram.com/@instausername'> Instagram: @instausername<a/> Lorem ipsum
```

---

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jp3gv4)

Comment: Thanks Pedro, worked fine. I just added a replace of the @ charachter in the link for the username.